# Trying to get year/month/day from date object but it returns 1970-01-01

Tags: php

I'm trying to do an script that returns the year, month and day but the response is always the same : `1970-01-01`.

I can't understand, it should change on every link and "google" ssl expiration date is not `1970-01-01`

**So, someone can see the error in the code?**

```
$url           = "https://www.google.es/";
$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get           = stream_context_create(array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "capture_peer_cert" => TRUE
    )
));
$read     = stream_socket_client("ssl://" . $orignal_parse . ":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert     = stream_context_get_params($read);
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
$valid_to = date(DATE_RFC2822, $certinfo['validTo_time_t']);
$time     = strtotime($valid_to);
$month    = date("F",$time);
$year     = date('Y', $time);
$day      = date('j', $time);

if ($month = "Januay") {
    $month = "01";
} else if ($month = "February") {
    $month = "02";
} else if ($month = "March") {
    $month = "03";
} else if ($month = "April") {
    $month = "04";
} else if ($month = "May") {
    $month = "05";
} else if ($month = "June") {
    $month = "06";
} else if ($month = "July") {
    $month = "07";
} else if ($month = "August") {
    $month = "08";
} else if ($month = "September") {
    $month = "09";
} else if ($month = "October") {
    $month = "10";
} else if ($month = "November") {
    $month = "11";
} else if ($month = "December") {
    $month = "12";
}
$strtime = strtotime($day ."/" . $month . "/" . $year);
$newdate = date('Y-m-d',$strtime);
echo $newdate;
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? How can we debug this is if we don't know any of the values you are working with?

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($time, $month, $year, $day);`?

Comment: Why do you `$month = date("F",$time);` then `if ($month = "Januay") {
    $month = "01";`? Why not just `$month = date("m",$time);` directly and skip the if's?

Comment: @Andreas thanks you very much

Comment: See my answer I just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strtotime function uses the character between the parts of the date to determine whether it is in American format or European format. Your call is using slashes so strtotime is looking for month/day/year but you are passing day/month/year. Try changing

```
$strtime = strtotime($day ."/" . $month . "/" . $year);
```

to

```
$strtime = strtotime($month ."/" . $day . "/" . $year);
```

Comment: Thanks you it worked but I should to change the ==> $newdate = date('Y-m-d',$strtime); to this===> $newdate = date('d-m-Y',$strtime);

Comment: Format newdate however you need it. You can also get rid of the extra variable by calling strtotime directly when creating `newdate` .... `$newdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($month ."/" . $day . "/" . $year););`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you have overworked your code to the max.
Date and strtotime are meant to work together, but by some reason you seem to keep them apart.
Keep this:

```
$url           = "https://www.google.es/";
$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get           = stream_context_create(array(
"ssl" => array(
    "capture_peer_cert" => TRUE
)
));
$read          = stream_socket_client("ssl://" . $orignal_parse . ":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert          = stream_context_get_params($read);
$certinfo      = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
$valid_to      = date(DATE_RFC2822, 
$certinfo['validTo_time_t']);
$time = strtotime($valid_to);
```

Then you just need:

```
$newdate = date('Y-m-d',$time);
```

And you are done!